# How to use delayed expansion with the iterator of the outer for-loop?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, delay, expansion

I cannot seem to find out, how I can use the iterator of the outer loop within the inner loop (in a batch file):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM for every folder in %mainfolder%
for /D %%s in (%mainfolder%\*) DO (
REM for every file in the subfolder %s
    for %%f in (%%s\*) do(
        some things with the files in that subfolder
    )
)
```

Where do I have to place the exclamation marks, so that I can actually use %s in the inner Loop? Right now, I get the Error

> "do(" kann syntaktisch nicht an dieser stelle verarbeitet werden
>   C:\fakepath> for %f in (%s*) do(

which means translated that **"do(" cannot be syntactically processed at this position.**

I am pretty sure that the problem actually has to do with the Delayed Expansion (actually, with not using it)

Comment: You are missing a space between the `do` and the opening parenthesis. To use `%%s` in the inner loop, .... use it. No need for delayed expansion

Comment: oh wow, that I didn't see this myself! thank you very much for the fast answer. do you think I should delete this question because of its stupidity?

Comment: *"I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work."* 
Thomas A. Edison. There are no stupid questions.

Comment: alright, then I'll leave it on for other people who don't realise how simple the problem is ^^ Would you add your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? Else, it would seem like it's an unsolved question und other people (who dont read comments) would waste time answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct the error, it is necessary to add a space between the `do` clause and the opening parenthesis of the code block.

The `%%s` replaceable parameter scope/visibility is anywhere inside the `for` loop that initializes it. So, it can be directly used inside the inner loop.